# How to run a luigi task with spark-submit and pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, luigi

I have a **luigi** python task which includes some pyspark libs. Now I would like to submit this task on mesos with spark-submit. What should I do to run it? Below is my code skeleton:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark import SparkContext

class myClass(SparkSubmitTask):
# date = luigi.DateParameter()

  def __init__(self, date):
    self.date = date # date is datetime.date.today().isoformat()

  def output(self):

  def input(self):

  def run(self):
    # Some functions are using pyspark libs

if __name__ == "__main__":
  luigi.run()
```

Without luigi, I'm submmitting this task as the following command-line:

```
/opt/spark/bin/spark-submit --master mesos://host:port --deploy-mode cluster --total-executor-cores 1 --driver-cores 1 --executor-memory 1G --driver-memory 1G my_module.py
```

Now the problem is how I can spark-submit the luigi task that includes  luigi command-line such as:

```
luigi --module my_module myClass --local-scheduler --date 2016-01
```

One more question is if my_module.py has a required task to finish first, do I need to do something more for it or just set the same as the current command-line?

I really appreciate for any hints or suggestions for this. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 7):

Luigi has some template Tasks. One of them called PySparkTask.
You can inherit from this class and override the properties:

https://github.com/spotify/luigi/blob/master/luigi/contrib/spark.py.

I haven't tested it but based on my experience with luigi I would have try this:

```
import my_module


class MyPySparkTask(PySparkTask):
    date = luigi.DateParameter()

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.__class__.__name__

    @property
    def master(self):
        return 'mesos://host:port'

    @property
    def deploy_mode(self):
        return 'cluster'

    @property
    def total_executor_cores(self):
        return 1

    @property
    def driver_cores(self):
        return 1

    @property
    def executor-memory(self):
        return 1G

    @property
    def driver-memory(self):
        return 1G

    def main(self, sc, *args):
        my_module.run(sc)

    def self.app_options():
        return [date]
```

Then you can run it with:
    luigi --module task_module MyPySparkTask --local-scheduler --date 2016-01

There is also an option to set the properties in a client.cfg file in order to make them the default values for other PySparkTasks:

```
[spark]
master: mesos://host:port
deploy_mode: cluster
total_executor_cores: 1
driver_cores: 1
executor-memory: 1G
driver-memory: 1G
```

Comment: Hi ayun12, thanks very much for your comment. I already inherit my class from SparkSubmitTask, can I use this class instead and how? If I use MyPySparkTask, you mean I just need to set spark commands in client.cfg and then run the command: "luigi --module task_module MyPySparkTask --local-scheduler --date 2016-01" as usual?

Comment: 1. You need to inherit from PySparkTask instead of SparkSubmitTask (like MyPySparkTask in the example above) and implement the logic in the 'main' method.

2. The configuration is the same as the SparkSubmitTask, did you define it in the client.cfg or by overriding properties?

3. The execution is similar to executing SparkSubmitTask

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. One thing I would like to ask is, in your code at main method, you call my_module.run(sc). However, as far as I know, luigi.Task that my_module function inherits from in task_module.py does not have parameter sc in method run. So you mean I have to override this method in task_module.py?

Comment: How and where would I set `PYSPARK_PYTHON`? My problem is that my workers use Python2.7 and my driver runs on Python3.5 - can I set this under '[spark]`? Can't find an example ..

Comment: @StefanFalk To use a different python for your executors, override `PySparkTask`'s `setup` method with something like:
    `def setup(self, conf):
        conf.set('spark.executorEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON', '/path/to/your/bin/python')`