# How do I run multiple spark jobs in series one after another on Pyspark?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

Currently I have several spark-submit *.sh files. Each file generates a table that is used in next file.

Is there a way to sequentially run these files one after another?

As of now I tried adding all the spark submit codes one after another in one file and tried

```
sh spark_submit_ordered_combined.sh
```

in terminal.
But this starts all the codes at one go.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Spark submit exits after the job is completed, are you launching spark-submit in the background? If not, can you show the content of your bash script?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a data pipeline framework as the input for the **'next file'** is required while the output of the previous `spark-submit` is still running. [Luigi](https://github.com/spotify/luigi) is A Python framework that helps you to build your desired pipelines of batch jobs. A task has `requires()`, `run()` and `output()` method to control workflow and dependencies between each task.

[By extending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39244648/how-to-run-a-luigi-task-with-spark-submit-and-pyspark) `PySparkTask` (for PySpark) or `SparkSubmitTask` class and override their properties, the pipeline in your case would be:

- **Task1**: output file 1, no required task
- **Task2**: output file2, requires file1
- **Task3**: output file3, requires file2
- ...

By this, the input of a task is the output of the other and so on. If one task was failed (says Task3), only Task3 has to re-submit because **file1 and file2 is already there**.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on [Apache Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/):

> Use airflow to author workflows as directed acyclic graphs (DAGs) of tasks. The airflow scheduler executes your tasks on an array of workers while following the specified dependencies.

Here is [Getting started with Airflow](https://towardsdatascience.com/getting-started-with-apache-airflow-df1aa77d7b1b) and this post to use [Airflow with Pyspark](https://blog.nzrs.net.nz/improving-data-workflows-with-airflow-and-pyspark/)